# ionic datepicker containing date and time column

Tags: android, ionic-framework, datetimepicker

I would like to display a datetime picker with ionic (angular) as followed:

[image: Example]

Description: Month and Day in first column, hour in 2nd and minutes in 3d column. Additionally I need to have the minutes only in 30min steps -> only options: 0, 30

In the documentation https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime the date and time is always in separate pickers and do not look very native on the ios preview...?

Could somebody help me with it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching and I think there is no way to put Month and day together in the same column along with day-of-the-week, you would have to define *dayValues* to define from your controller which values you want to display.

You could do it statically like this:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="DDDDDDDDD H:mm" 
         dayValues="Mon.1.Jan,Tue.2.Jan, Wed.3.Jan"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

And you would only have 3 values in the 'Day Column', and another 2 columns for hour and minutes. But the real solution for this would be having you html file like this:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="DDDDDDDDD H:mm" 
         [dayValues]="pickerArray"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

so you can load the first column from your .ts file:

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
     pickerArray: string[]=[];

     constructor(){
        this.fillMyArray()
     }
     
     ...
}
```

I'll let you think how to fill it! good luck.